# Не обновляется сайт на Android Chrome

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

### Не обновляется сайт на .php

Написал простенький сайт: (index.php)

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel=stylesheet href="styles/index.css">
    <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="white">

<?php

require 'functions.php';

/********** GLOBALS ************/
$counter;
$request;
$answer;
$trans;
$today=date('d.m.Y');

DrawHead();
DrawMenu();
DrawSearchForm();

/***************************** ENGINE *******************************/
if (isset($_POST["request"])) {
        $request=$_POST["input"];
        Search($request);
}

?>

    </body>
</html>
```

### Проблема:

Каждый день данные актуализируются внутри функций. Производится выборка из базы данных (текстовый файл) и работа с выбранными данными. Но вот беда.. Когда на следующий день с мобильного Android Chrome захожу на сайт, данные по прежнему "вчерашние". Ни очистка кэш ни перезапуск приложения ни обновление страницы не помогают. При открытии сайта с компьютера все актуализируется и дальше на телефоне уже отображается актуальная информация..

Comment: т е пока вы с компьютера не откроете сайт, на телефоне данные не актульны на "сегодняшний" день? я верно понял?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: Сайт на локалке находится?

Comment: Нет. Сайт на домене в интернет.

Comment: Очень странная ситуация. Может с браузером самим чтото? Попробуйте другим открыть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все дело оказалось в разных часовых поясах моего местоположения и местоположения сервера. На момент, когда у меня уже новый день, на сервере еще "вчера". С наступлением нового дня на сервере проблема исчезает на всех устройствах.